# Joining specific tuples within a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I've been asking quite a bit recently, and don't feel too much comfortably needing this much help but this algorithm looks real tough.

I have a list of tuples like this:

```
[('12 Mar 2011',), ('152', 'Farko', 'Kier'), ('153', 'Park', 'Pub'), ('09 Mar 2011',), ('158', 'Diving', 'Jogging')]
```

The tuple with date will always have `len == 1` . Now, I need to join each preceeding date with all the following non-date tuples. The number of non-date tuples will always be undefined. Date tuple will join every non-date tuple in the sequence until it approaches next date tuple, then that tuple must join all the following non date tuples and so on. The final outcome should be this:

```
 [('152', 'Farko', 'Kier', '12 Mar 2011'), ('153', 'Park', 'Pub', '12 Mar 2011'), ('158', 'Diving', 'Jogging', '09 Mar 2011',]
```

If you can't provide a ready code, maybe some hint where to look at, what method because I can't think of anything in my toolkit that can do well here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could write this using `itertools.groupby`, but an imperative generator function is likely to be more readable:

```
def join_dates(l):
    date = None
    for t in l:
        if len(t) == 1:
            date = t
        else:
            yield t + date
```

For completeness, here's the `itertools` solution:

```
from itertools import groupby
[t + ds[0] for ds, ts in zip(*[(list(g) for _, g in groupby(l, len))] * 2) for t in ts]
```

Answer (score 4):

Something like this:

```
In [60]: ans=[]

In [61]: lis=[('12 Mar 2011',), ('152', 'Farko', 'Kier'), ('153', 'Park', 'Pub'), ('09 Mar 2011',), ('158', 'Diving', 'Jogging')]

In [62]: date=None

In [63]: for x in lis:
    if len(x)==1:
        date=list(x)
    else:
        if date:
            ans.append(list(x)+date)
   ....:         

In [64]: ans
Out[64]: 
[['152', 'Farko', 'Kier', '12 Mar 2011'],
 ['153', 'Park', 'Pub', '12 Mar 2011'],
 ['158', 'Diving', 'Jogging', '09 Mar 2011']]
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution too :) btw what interpreter are you using that gives these `ins` and `outs` on the left ?